# Plot concentric circles in cytoscape GUI (NOT cytoscape.js)

Tags: data-visualization, cytoscape

I want to use the cytoscape GUI tool (https://cytoscape.org/) to draw something like this (please see the image here [concentric circle graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gjC2.jpg)

My data looks like this, where each node belongs to one of the 2 classes.

Node,class

'1','dog'

'2','cat'

'3','cat'

'4','dog'

'5','dog'

...

...

I want the outer circle to have 'dog' nodes and the inner circle to consists of 'cat' nodes.

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Cytoscape is a GUI software, kinda like photoshop, so there is no code for it. Please see if this helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a couple of classes, you should be able to do this using a circular layout, or perhaps even simpler, a group attributes layout.  If you do a group attributes layout, you will get multiple circles, but they won't be concentric.  However, it should be easy to select the smaller circle and move it to be inside of the larger circle.  You may need to shrink it a bit using the Node Layout tools scale option.